# How to create surface from 3-D numpy array in Pyopengl?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pyqt5, pyopengl, python-moderngl

I have created a 3-d numpy array consisting of X, Y, and Z axis coordinates. Now I am trying to create a surface using these points in opengl but all I have got success is in creating wire model something like this below [image: model]. Can anyone suggest changes in my code to form actual 3-D surface from data?
Data file used link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PWbNIt3xbchtQ9HIIS96k7ZjblzPO_wO

Code:-

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.arrays.vbo as glvbo
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np
import Backend_algo as Sb
import sys
import ctypes


def compile_vertex_shader(source):
    """Compile a vertex shader from source."""
    vertex_shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    gl.glShaderSource(vertex_shader, source)
    gl.glCompileShader(vertex_shader)
    # check compilation error
    result = gl.glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader))
    return vertex_shader


def compile_fragment_shader(source):
    """Compile a fragment shader from source."""
    fragment_shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.glShaderSource(fragment_shader, source)
    gl.glCompileShader(fragment_shader)
    result = gl.glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader))
    return fragment_shader


def link_shader_program(vertex_shader, fragment_shader):
    """Create a shader program with from compiled shaders."""
    program = gl.glCreateProgram()
    gl.glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    gl.glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)
    gl.glLinkProgram(program)

    result = gl.glGetProgramiv(program, gl.GL_LINK_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
    return program


VS = '''

attribute vec3 position;


uniform float right;
uniform float bottom;
uniform float left;
uniform float top;
uniform float far;
uniform float near;

void main() {

    mat4 testmat = mat4(
            vec4(2.0 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0),
            vec4(0, 2.0 / (top - bottom), 0, 0),
            vec4(0, 0, -2.0 / (far - near), 0),
            vec4(-(right + left) / (right - left), -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom), -(far + near) / (far - near), 1)
    );

    gl_Position = testmat * vec4(position, 1.);

}

'''
FS = '''
#version 450
// Output variable of the fragment shader, which is a 4D vector containing the
// RGBA components of the pixel color.
uniform vec3 triangleColor;
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(triangleColor, 1.0);
}
'''


class GLPlotWidget3D(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        # QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        super(GLPlotWidget3D, self).__init__()
        # self.parent = args[0]
        self.width, self.height = 100, 100
        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom = 21000, -21000, 10, -10
        self.data = np.zeros((3, 10, 2))
        self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.data)

        self.showMaximized()

    def initializeGL(self):
        vs = Sb.compile_vertex_shader(VS)
        fs = Sb.compile_fragment_shader(FS)
        self.shaders_program = link_shader_program(vs, fs)
        self.e = np.load(('three.npy'), mmap_mode='r')
        self.e = np.array(self.e, dtype=np.float32)

        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom, self.far, self.near = self.e[:, :, 1].min(), self.e[:, : , 1].max(), self.e[:, : , 0].min(), self.e[:, : , 0].max(), self.e[:, : , 2].max(), self.e[:, : , 2].min()

    def ortho_view(self):
        right = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "right")
        gl.glUniform1f(right, self.right)

        left = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "left")
        gl.glUniform1f(left, self.left)

        top = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "top")
        gl.glUniform1f(top, self.top)

        bottom = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "bottom")
        gl.glUniform1f(bottom, self.bottom)

        far = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "far")
        gl.glUniform1f(far, self.far)

        near = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "near")
        gl.glUniform1f(near, self.near)


    def paintGL(self):
        self.resizeGL(self.width, self.height)
        gl.glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glUseProgram(self.shaders_program)

        buffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
        stride = self.e.strides[0]
        offset = ctypes.c_void_p(1)
        loc = gl.glGetAttribLocation(self.shaders_program, "position")
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.e.nbytes, self.e, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, self.e.shape[0])

        self.ortho_view()
        uni_color = gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program, "triangleColor")
        gl.glUniform3f(uni_color, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)


    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = GLPlotWidget3D()
    editor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'three.npy' contains a 3 dimensional array (7782 x 24 x3) with the vertex coordinates of a tube. The 3rd dimension with a size of 3 contains the *x*, *y* and *z* coordinates of the vertices. The vertices are organized in 7782 rings with 24 point around the circumference.

Read the vertex coordinates to a flatten buffer (the numpy array is flatten automatically by [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html)).
Generate an array of indices (indices of the vertex buffer). The indices describe [`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) primitives which stack up 7781 rings. Each ring consisting of 24 quads around the circumference.

```py
self.e = np.load(('three.npy'), mmap_mode='r')
self.e = np.array(self.e, dtype=np.float32)

self.elems = []
ring_c = self.e.shape[1]
slice_c = self.e.shape[0]
for si in range(slice_c-1):
    self.elems += [si*ring_c, si*ring_c]
    for ri in range(ring_c+1):
        ie = ri % ring_c
        self.elems += [ie+si*ring_c, ie+(si+1)*ring_c]
self.elems = np.array(self.elems, dtype=np.int32)
```

The *x*  and *y* component of the vertices are in range [-10, 10], but the z component is in range [3, 29724672].

```non
x min      x max     y min      y max     z min      z max
-10.589109 10.517833 -10.464569 10.594374 29724672.0 3.1618009
```

I recommend to define a scale for the z coordinate:

```py
self.scaleZ = 0.000001
```

Create a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) (`GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`) for the vertices and an [Index buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) for the indices:

```py
self.vertexbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.e, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

self.elementbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elems, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
```

Specif the array of vertex coordinates. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers).
The *stride* and offset *parameter* of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) have to be 0.
*stride* specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes it has to be either `3*self.e.itemsize` (12) or `0`. 0 has a special meaning and and interprets the attributes as to be tightly packed. If *stride* is 0 it is computed by the *size* and *type* parameter.
*offset* hast to be `ctypes.c_void_p(0)` or `None`, because the offset of the 1 attribute in the array is 0.
In any case the unit of *stride* and *offset* is bytes.

```py
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)
stride = 0 # 3*self.e.itemsize
offset = None # ctypes.c_void_p(0)
loc = self.attrib['position']
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)
```

The [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type is `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and the index buffer has to be bound before the elements are drawn by [`glDrawElements`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDrawElements.html):

```py
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)

self.perspective_view()
gl.glUniform3f(self.uniform['triangleColor'], 1, 1, 1)
gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, self.elems.size, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

Instead of specifying an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) matrix in the vertex shader, I recommend to use matrix [Uniform variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) for the projection, respectively model and view transformation.
The projection matrix defines the projection of the 3 dimensional viewing volume to the 2 dimensional viewport. The view matrix defines the viewing position of view and viewing direction onto the scene. The model matrix defines the scale and animation of the mode.

```c
attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 u_proj;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_model;

void main() {

    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * u_model * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Get the attribute index and uniform locations after the shader program is linked:

```py
vs = compile_vertex_shader(VS)
fs = compile_fragment_shader(FS)
self.shaders_program = link_shader_program(vs, fs)
self.attrib = { a : gl.glGetAttribLocation (self.shaders_program, a) for a in ['position'] }
print(self.attrib)
self.uniform = { u : gl.glGetUniformLocation (self.shaders_program, u) for u in ['u_model', 'u_view', 'u_proj', "triangleColor"] }
print(self.uniform)
```

For a 3D look, I recommend to use [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) rather than [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection).
Use [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) to set the matrices.

```py
# projection matrix
aspect, ta, near, far = self.width/self.height, np.tan(np.radians(90.0) / 2), 0.1, 50
proj = np.matrix(((1/ta/aspect, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1/ta, 0, 0), (0, 0, -(far+near)/(far-near), -1), (0, 0, -2*far*near/(far-near), 0)), np.float32)

# view matrix
view = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -30, 1)), np.float32)

# model matrix
c, s = math.cos(self.angle), math.sin(self.angle)
model = scale

gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_proj'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, proj)
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_view'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, view)
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_model'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, model)
```

Full example:
(The fragment shader tints the fragments dependent on their depth)

[image]

```py
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.arrays.vbo as glvbo
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np
#import Backend_algo as Sb
import sys
import ctypes
import os
import math

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def compile_vertex_shader(source):
    """Compile a vertex shader from source."""
    vertex_shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    gl.glShaderSource(vertex_shader, source)
    gl.glCompileShader(vertex_shader)
    # check compilation error
    result = gl.glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader))
    return vertex_shader

def compile_fragment_shader(source):
    """Compile a fragment shader from source."""
    fragment_shader = gl.glCreateShader(gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.glShaderSource(fragment_shader, source)
    gl.glCompileShader(fragment_shader)
    result = gl.glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader))
    return fragment_shader

def link_shader_program(vertex_shader, fragment_shader):
    """Create a shader program with from compiled shaders."""
    program = gl.glCreateProgram()
    gl.glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    gl.glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)
    gl.glLinkProgram(program)

    result = gl.glGetProgramiv(program, gl.GL_LINK_STATUS)
    if not (result):
        raise RuntimeError(gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
    return program

VS = '''
attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 u_proj;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_model;

void main() {

    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * u_model * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
'''

FS = '''
#version 450
out vec4 outColor;

uniform vec3 triangleColor;

void main()
{
    float d = 1.0 - gl_FragCoord.z;
    outColor = vec4(triangleColor * d, 1.0);
}
'''

class GLPlotWidget3D(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        # QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        super(GLPlotWidget3D, self).__init__()
        # self.parent = args[0]
        self.width, self.height = 100, 100
        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom = 21000, -21000, 10, -10
        self.data = np.zeros((3, 10, 2))
        self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.data)

        self.showMaximized()

    def initializeGL(self):

        vs = compile_vertex_shader(VS)
        fs = compile_fragment_shader(FS)
        self.shaders_program = link_shader_program(vs, fs)
        self.attrib = { a : gl.glGetAttribLocation (self.shaders_program, a) for a in ['position'] }
        print(self.attrib)
        self.uniform = { u : gl.glGetUniformLocation (self.shaders_program, u) for u in ['u_model', 'u_view', 'u_proj', "triangleColor"] }
        print(self.uniform)

        self.e = np.load((os.path.join(sourceFileDir,'three.npy')), mmap_mode='r')
        self.e = np.array(self.e, dtype=np.float32)
        print(self.e.shape)

        self.elems = []
        ring_c = self.e.shape[1]
        slice_c = self.e.shape[0]
        for si in range(slice_c-1):
            self.elems += [si*ring_c, si*ring_c]
            for ri in range(ring_c+1):
                ie = ri % ring_c
                self.elems += [ie+si*ring_c, ie+(si+1)*ring_c]

        self.elems = np.array(self.elems, dtype=np.int32)

        self.vertexbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.e, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        self.elementbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elems, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        self.scaleZ = 0.000001
        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom, self.far, self.near = self.e[:, :, 1].min(), self.e[:, : , 1].max(), self.e[:, : , 0].min(), self.e[:, : , 0].max(), self.e[:, : , 2].max(), self.e[:, : , 2].min()
        print(self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom, self.far, self.near)
        self.far *= self.scaleZ
        self.near *= self.scaleZ
        self.angle = 0.0

        self.GLtimer = QTimer()
        self.GLtimer.setInterval(10)
        self.GLtimer.timeout.connect(self.redraw)
        self.GLtimer.start()

    def redraw(self):
        self.angle += 0.01
        self.update()

    def perspective_view(self):

        # projection matrix
        aspect, ta, near, far = self.width/self.height, np.tan(np.radians(90.0) / 2), 10, 50
        proj = np.matrix(((1/ta/aspect, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1/ta, 0, 0), (0, 0, -(far+near)/(far-near), -1), (0, 0, -2*far*near/(far-near), 0)), np.float32)

        # view matrix
        view = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -30, 1)), np.float32)

        # model matrix
        c, s = math.cos(self.angle), math.sin(self.angle)
        scale = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, self.scaleZ, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        rotZ = np.array(((c, s, 0, 0), (-s, c, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32) 
        rotY = np.matrix(((0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        trans = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, (self.near - self.far)/2, 1)), np.float32)
        model = scale * trans * rotY * rotZ

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_proj'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, proj)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_view'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, view)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_model'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, model)


    def paintGL(self):
        self.resizeGL(self.width, self.height)
        gl.glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        gl.glUseProgram(self.shaders_program)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)
        stride = 0 # 3*self.e.itemsize
        offset = None # ctypes.c_void_p(0)
        loc = self.attrib['position']
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)

        self.perspective_view()
        gl.glUniform3f(self.uniform['triangleColor'], 1, 1, 1)
        #gl.glPolygonMode(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_LINE)
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, self.elems.size, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = GLPlotWidget3D()
    editor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this issue is resolver. Also can u tell me more about this lightning how to use it on surface of cylinder such that if there is any triangle falls out of average diameter it is of different color

Comment: @AKS In this example is not lighting. The fragments are colored dependent on there depth. For a light model you would have to compute the normal vectors for the fragment (on the CPU) and to specify an additional attribute for the normal vectors (1 normal vector for each vertex coordinate).

Comment: So what I understand is that I have to create a 1-D array of the colour and pass it in fragment shader. But I cannot understand what will be the code in fragment shader and the length of array will be equal to the number of data points or the number of triangle we are rendering?

Comment: @AKS Investigate the draw call `gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, self.elems.size, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)`. `self.elems.size` is th number of indices. The list of indices is interpreted as list of triangle primitives because of the primitive type `gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. If you would use `gl.glDrawArrays`, then you have to pass the number of vertices.